# How to Get a Specific Value from Lookupset Function

Tags: ssrs-2008

My data Report like this,

```
ID Name
1  Abc 
2  Abc 
3  Abc 
4  Abc 

=Join(LookUpSet(Fields!name.Value,Fields!name.Value,Fields!ID.Value,
                "Dataset1",",")
```

After Using `LookupSet` function I'm Getting Value as

```
ID         Name
1,2,3,4    Abc
```

`Code.GetUrl(Join(LookUpSet(Fields!ID.Value,Fields!ID.Value,
                             Fields!ID.Value,"Dataset1"),""))`

This Above code is to set HyperLink, code.GetUrl() returs a hyperlink with the Id, but I cant Get Particular ID in the link. Getting just ID 1 for All the Id's link..........

Kindly Help......

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss a parentheses in this line?

```
Join(LookUpSet(Fields!name.Value,Fields!name.Value,Fields!ID.Value,
                "Dataset1"),",")
```

And you missed a `,` in the next line?

```
Code.GetUrl(Join(LookUpSet(Fields!ID.Value,Fields!ID.Value,
                             Fields!ID.Value,"Dataset1"),","))
```